# Anomaly detection for contaminated dataset with high interclass variation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, autoencoder

I want to build a anomaly detection algorithm. The dataset I am dealing with consists of images with a **high inter class variation** like shown in the pictures below. The amount of trainings images is greater then 1,000,000.

[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd image]
[image: 3rd image]

The neuronal network should detect features in the images, with very little occurrences. Those features are not known beforehand, but part of the (trainings-)dataset. In other words, this is a polluted traingingsset.

I have tried to train a Autoencoder with little success. Based on the description in this [article](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and my own experience **Autoencoders** work best for very similar images, what is not the case in my specific dataset.

What other neuronal network types you would recommend for this task? Is it necessary to use a image classification in order to get a more homogeneous dataset as part of the "preprocessing"?